# How to do serial communication without using USBManager?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, serial-port

https://github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial This is the library I used. The way I want to do is to do serial communication through cts/rts. But the usbmanager.getdevicelist shows an empty value and the program doesn't work.

```
private class ConnectionThread extends Thread { 
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("device_log", device.toString());
            Log.d("connection_log", connection.toString());
            Log.d("serialPort_log", serialPort.toString());
            serialPort = UsbSerialDevice.createUsbSerialDevice(device, connection);
            if (serialPort != null) {
                if (serialPort.open()) {
                    serialPortConnected = true;
                    serialPort.setBaudRate(BAUD_RATE);
                    serialPort.setDataBits(UsbSerialInterface.DATA_BITS_8);
                    serialPort.setStopBits(UsbSerialInterface.STOP_BITS_1);
                    serialPort.setParity(UsbSerialInterface.PARITY_NONE);
                    /**
                     * Current flow control Options:
                     * UsbSerialInterface.FLOW_CONTROL_OFF
                     * UsbSerialInterface.FLOW_CONTROL_RTS_CTS only for CP2102 and FT232
                     * UsbSerialInterface.FLOW_CONTROL_DSR_DTR only for CP2102 and FT232
                     */
                    serialPort.setFlowControl(UsbSerialInterface.FLOW_CONTROL_RTS_CTS);
                    serialPort.read(mCallback);
                    serialPort.getCTS(ctsCallback);
                    serialPort.getDSR(dsrCallback);
                    
                    //
                    // Some Arduinos would need some sleep because firmware wait some time to know whether a new sketch is going 
                    // to be uploaded or not
                    //Thread.sleep(2000); // sleep some. YMMV with different chips.
                    
                    // Everything went as expected. Send an intent to MainActivity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_USB_READY);
                    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
                } else {
                    // Serial port could not be opened, maybe an I/O error or if CDC driver was chosen, it does not really fit
                    // Send an Intent to Main Activity
                    if (serialPort instanceof CDCSerialDevice) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_CDC_DRIVER_NOT_WORKING);
                        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_USB_DEVICE_NOT_WORKING);
                        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // No driver for given device, even generic CDC driver could not be loaded
                Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_USB_NOT_SUPPORTED);
                context.sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Because of this situation, I couldn't use usbmanager itself, so the serial communication connection in TTL method using another library was successful. However, the current code related to flow control does not exist in this library, so it is blocked. I'm not very knowledgeable about Android, so can you recommend some related materials? Since usbmanager cannot perform usb-to-serial communication itself due to a problem with the current connection method, it is a situation in which serial communication must be performed only in the TTL method through direct connection with hardware, and additional flow control is required.

https://github.com/cepr/android-serialport-api

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val SERIAL_PORT_NAME = "ttyAMA4"
    val SERIAL_BAUDRATE = 9600
    var serialPort: SerialPort? = null
    var inputStream: InputStream? = null
    var outputStream: OutputStream? = null
    lateinit var serialThread: Thread


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        OpenSerialPort(SERIAL_PORT_NAME)
        StartRxThread()
        
    }

    private fun OpenSerialPort(name: String) {
        val serialPortFinder : SerialPortFinder = SerialPortFinder()
        val devices: Array<String> = serialPortFinder.allDevices
        val devicesPath: Array<String> = serialPortFinder.allDevicesPath

        for (device in devices) {
            if (device.contains(name, true)) {
                val index = devices.indexOf(device)
                Log.e("serialPoet ", Arrays.toString(devicesPath))
                serialPort = SerialPort(File(devicesPath.get(index)), SERIAL_BAUDRATE, 0)
                break
            }
        }

        Log.e("serialPoet ", serialPort.toString())

        serialPort?.let {
            inputStream = it.inputStream
            outputStream = it.outputStream
        }
    }

    private fun StartRxThread() {
        if (inputStream == null) {
            Log.e("SerialExam", "Can't open inputstream")
            return
        }

        serialThread = Thread {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    var buffer = ByteArray(64)
                    val size = inputStream?.read(buffer)
                    OnReceivedData(buffer, size ?: 0)
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }
        serialThread.start()
    }

    private fun OnReceivedData(buffer: ByteArray, size: Int) {
        if (size < 1) return


        var strBuilder = StringBuilder()
        for (i in 0 until size) {
            strBuilder.append(String.format("%02x ", buffer[i]))
        }

        Log.d("SerialExam", "rx: " + strBuilder.toString())

    }

    private fun OnSendData(data: ByteArray) {
        try {
            outputStream?.write(data)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    
    override fun onDestroy() {
        serialThread.interrupt()
        serialPort?.close()

        super.onDestroy()
    }


}
```

Is there a way to control the cts/rts flow in this code? The method via usbmanager is not possible.

Comment: Can you [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71199930/edit) to include which hardware/OS version you are testing on/expect your software to run.

Comment: The OS currently in use is 5.5.1 Lollipop and the hardware is FTDI chip RS485.

Comment: *"the program doesn't work."* -- Not a useful description of what the actual issue might be.  *"the hardware is FTDI chip RS485*" -- RS-485 does not have hardware flow control using CTS/RTS control lines.